# deleting a specific line from a dataframe python NLP

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, data-preprocessing

I am trying to preprocess my data for NLP model. I wrote this code to remove numbers, symbols and hyper links. But now I want to delete every line that has a specific instance of the word 'system'. I don't seem to figure how to do that. `df` is my dataframe and `df['Content']` is where I have the text I want to delete the line from.

for example the text can be :

"system: hi im the line that is meant to be deleted
Leena: this line must not be deleted
system: hi again im the line that is meant to be deleted "

the output should be :
Leena: this line must not be deleted

```
def CleaningTXT(df):
    Allchat=list()
    lines=df['Content'].values.tolist()
    for text in lines:
        text=text.lower()
        #remove links
        pattern = re.compile('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')
        text = pattern.sub('', text)
        #remove session join/leave
        pattern = re.compile('new party join session')
        text = pattern.sub('', text)
        pattern = re.compile('new party leave session')
        text = pattern.sub('', text)
        #remove sympols
        text = re.sub(r"[,.\"!@#$%^&*(){}?/;`~:<>+=-]", "", text)
        #seperating words
        tokens = word_tokenize(text)
        table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
        stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
        #removing numbers
        words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
        words = ' '.join(words)
        Allchat.append(words)
    return Allchat
```

Answer (score 0):

hope I understand your request.
try the following:

```py
def CleaningTXT(df):
    Allchat=list()
    #Added
    index_to_drop = df[ df['Content'].str.contains('system')].index
    df.drop(index_to_drop, inplace = True)

    lines=df['Content'].values.tolist()
    for text in lines:
        text=text.lower()
        #remove links
        pattern = re.compile('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')
        text = pattern.sub('', text)
        #remove session join/leave
        pattern = re.compile('new party join session')
        text = pattern.sub('', text)
        pattern = re.compile('new party leave session')
        text = pattern.sub('', text)
        #remove sympols
        text = re.sub(r"[,.\"!@#$%^&*(){}?/;`~:<>+=-]", "", text)
        #seperating words
        tokens = word_tokenize(text)
        table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
        stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
        #removing numbers
        words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
        words = ' '.join(words)
        Allchat.append(words)
    return Allchat
```

Comment: you are dropping the whole text and all the lines in it . while i want to delete only the line it occurred in